# model.findByID not working mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongoose

mongoose is not supporting the callbacks in the in the models functions so i want to convert it into promises but idk what mistake i am doing in writing it into promises

i want to covert this into promises

module.exports.create = function(req, res){
Post.findById(req.body.post, function(err, post){

```
    if (post){
        Comment.create({
            content: req.body.content,
            post: req.body.post,
            user: req.user._id
        }, function(err, comment){
            // handle error

            post.comments.push(comment);
            post.save();

            res.redirect('/');
        });
    }

});
```

}

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: used async await and it worked